# How to optimise the Docker build process in JenkinsPipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am having trouble in optimizing my docker build step.

Below is my use case:

In my `jenkinsfile` I am building 3 docker images.

1. from `*docker/test/Dockerfile*`
2. from `*docker/dev/Dockerfile*`

```
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'docker build -t Test -f docker/test/Dockerfile .'
            sh 'set +x && eval $(/usr/local/bin/aws-login/aws-login.sh $AWS_ACCOUNT jenkins eu-west-2) \
              && docker build -t DEV --build-arg S3_FILE_NAME=environment.dev.ts \
              --build-arg CONFIG_S3_BUCKET_URI=s3://bucket \
              --build-arg AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
              --build-arg AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
              --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
              --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
              -f docker/dev/Dockerfile .'
            sh 'set +x && eval $(/usr/local/bin/aws-login/aws-login.sh $AWS_ACCOUNT jenkins eu-west-2) \
              && docker build -t QA --build-arg S3_FILE_NAME=environment.qa.ts \
              --build-arg CONFIG_S3_BUCKET_URI=s3://bucket \
              --build-arg AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
              --build-arg AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
              --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
              --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
              -f docker/dev/Dockerfile .'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'docker run --rm TEST npm run test'
        }
    }
```

Below is my two docker file:

**docker/test/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:lts

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-key update && apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD sh ./docker/test/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**docker/dev/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:lts as dev-builder

ARG CONFIG_S3_BUCKET_URI
ARG S3_FILE_NAME
ARG AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev -y
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py

RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN aws s3 cp "$CONFIG_S3_BUCKET_URI/$S3_FILE_NAME" src/environments/environment.dev.ts
RUN cat src/environments/environment.dev.ts

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-dev

FROM nginx:stable
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=dev-builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Every time it takes 20-25 mins to build the images.

Is there any way I can optimize the docker file for a better build process?

suggestion are welcome. `RUN npm run build-dev` uses `package.json` to install the dependencies. which is one on the reason that it install all dependency for every build.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of base images and multi stage builds to speed up your builds.

**Base image with pre-installed packages/dependencies**

Stuff like installing python3, pip, google-chrome, awscli etc need not be done every build. These layers might get cached if you are building on single machine but if you have multiple build machines or clean the cache, you will be re-building these layers unnecessarily. You can build a base image which already has these stuff and use this new image as the base for your app.

**Multi stage builds**

You are copying your source code and then doing `npm install`. Even if `package.json` has not changed, the layer will be re-built if any other file in source code might have changed.

You can create a multi stage dockerfile where you just copy the package.json in the first stage and run `npm install` and other such commands. This layer will be re-built only if package.json is changed.

In your second stage, you can just copy the npm cache from first stage.

```
FROM node:lts as dev-builder
WORKDIR /cache/
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-dev

FROM NEW_BASE_IMAGE_WITH_CHROME_ETC_DEPENDENCIES
COPY --from=node_cache /cache/ .
COPY . . 
<snip>
```

Identify any other such optimisations that you can make.